# Create thumbnail of image based on face/object detection - java

Tags: java, image, opencv, face-detection, object-detection

My main goal is Automatic Cropping image of fix width which focus on important object.cropping image without losing our main object from image.

i'm creating postboxlike facebook where when user insert url they get thumbnail of images of this url.

you can see in following images what I really want.

[image: Image1] [image: Image1 thumbnail]

[image: Image2] [image: Image2 thumbnail]

and **I Illustrated my problem in following screenshots.**

when i try to getting thumbnail of images of [9gag.com/gag/aG9206z](http://9gag.com/gag/aG9206z)
i get [image]

my **algorithm** is simple as following

1. get image by url
2. resize its width to 500px(which i want)
3. find x = (centre point of its height)-130 because i want height of 260
4. crop resized image from (0,x) to (500,260)
   which is centred cropped image.

here i use [imgscalr – Java Image Scaling Library](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

and when post same link on facebook it looks like [image]

so any library available in Java for detect face/object from image.
or any possible way for solve this problem.

updated : after some research i find **opencv** which i can use for solve this problem but i never use it.

Comment: Have you got any solution here/

Comment: No still not. Currently i'm cropping image from centre,may be in future i implement better algorithms.